# Makefile: test makefile for comparison

Tags: makefile, grep

i need to make a makefile which compares my written command grep output with .out file. The input text file which grep searches is in tests/*.test.

Beta's answer was very helpfull, except i cannot understand why this makefile

```
INPUT_DIR=tests

OUTPUT_DIR=outputs

FILES=$(wildcard ${INPUT_DIR}/*.test)

TEST_LIST = ${FILES:${INPUT_DIR}/%.test=%.diff}

.PHONY: all clean distclean

all: ${TEST_LIST}
    echo ${FILES}
    echo ${TEST_LIST}
${TEST_LIST}: ${INPUT_DIR}/%.test ${OUTPUT_DIR}/%.out
    ./grep apple $< >STDOUT
    diff STDOUT ${OUTPUT_DIR}/$*.out > $@
${INPUT_DIR}/%.test:
    echo $@
${OUTPUT_DIR}/%.out:
    echo $@
clean:
    rm -f ${FILES}
```

using `make makefile all -n`

```
make: Nothing to be done for `makefile'. 
echo tests/%.test 
echo outputs/%.out 
./grep apple tests/%.test >STDOUT diff STDOUT outputs/.out > 1.diff 
./grep apple tests/%.test >STDOUT diff STDOUT outputs/.out > 2.diff 
./grep apple tests/%.test >STDOUT diff STDOUT outputs/.out > 3.diff 
echo tests/1.test tests/2.test tests/3.test 
echo 1.diff 2.diff 3.diff
```

and using `make makefile all`

```
make: Nothing to be done for `makefile'. 
echo tests/%.test tests/%.test 
echo outputs/%.out outputs/%.out 
./grep apple tests/%.test >STDOUT
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is (or exactly what you're trying to do), but your `all` rule almost certainly doesn't do what you intend.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear, but since you use the file `STDOUT` as an intermediate file, and you use it for every comparison, and you use it for nothing else, I advise you to combine the rules:

```
%.diff: ${INPUT_DIR}/%.test ${OUTPUT_DIR}/%.out
    ./grep apple $< >STDOUT  # Do you really have an executable called "grep"?
    diff STDOUT ${OUTPUT_DIR}/$*.out > $@
```

Also, your `all` rule doesn't do what you expect. Try this:

```
all:
    @echo you must specify a target, e.g. outputs/foo.diff
```